# how to search a pattern using regex and append something to it using awk?

Tags: regex, awk

I'm trying to search a pattern using regex and once found wanted to append something to using `awk`.

Example:

```
abc/def/ghi/jkl/Io_LogUserVal[29]
```

Expected:

```
abc/def/ghi/jkl/Io_LogUserVal_reg[29]
```

I tried

```
awk -F "/" '{gsub(/Io_(\w+)/,$NF"_reg"); print$0}'
```

Comment: Please someone explain me what is $NF there. I read in the manual NF is the number of fields buy it does not make sense to me in this case.

Comment: @aalku: `$NF` is the value of last field. if `NF` is 3 then `$NF` represents value of `$3`. It is used in cases, when we don't have to dynamically identify the number representing the last field value, but just use `$NF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [GNU Awk gensub()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to use a regex match,

```
awk '{$NF=gensub(/^(.+)_(.+)\[(.+)\]$/,"\\1_\\2_reg[\\3]","g",$NF);}1' file
abc/def/ghi/jkl/Io_LogUserVal_reg[29]
```

Once you match the last field (`$NF`) with the regex `(.+)_(.+)\[(.+)\]` modify the captured groups as you wish. `(.+)` represents match any character multiple times.

Comment: Your solution is more flexible than mine. I like capture groups a lot more than gsub. But if they want to use gsub it is easy too in this case.

Comment: @aalku: Appreciate your feedback, but `gensub()` is `GNU Awk` speicifc, whereas `gsub()` is `POSIX` standard.

Answer (score 0):

Take the right one you need:

#### You may want to have this?

```
awk -F'/' '$NF~/^Io/{$0=$0"_reg"}7'
```

#### If you just want to check the pattern in whole line, then:

```
awk -F'/' '/Io/{$0=$0"_reg"}7'
```

#### If take your input/output example, this line should go:

```
kent$  awk -F'/' -v OFS="/" '$NF~/^Io/{sub(/\W/,"_reg&",$NF)}7'<<<"abc/def/ghi/jkl/Io_LogUserVal[29]"                                                                       
abc/def/ghi/jkl/Io_LogUserVal_reg[29]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&` to be replaced by the matched block.

```
awk '{gsub(/Io_(\w+)/,"&_reg"); print$0}'
```

If you want to replace only on the last field you can do it this way, adding `-v OFS="/"` and `$NF`:

```
awk -F "/" -v OFS="/" '{gsub(/Io_(\w+)/,"&_reg", $NF); print$0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with sed -

```
echo "abc/def/ghi/jkl/Io_LogUserVal[29]"| sed 's/Io_LogUserVal/Io_LogUserVal_reg/g'
abc/def/ghi/jkl/Io_LogUserVal_reg[29]

echo "abc/def/ghi/jkl/Io_LogUserVal[29]"| sed '/Io/s/UserVal/UserVal_reg/g'
abc/def/ghi/jkl/Io_LogUserVal_reg[29]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "abc/def/ghi/jkl/Io_LogUserVal[29]"| awk '{sub(/Val\[/,"Val_reg[")}1'

abc/def/ghi/jkl/Io_LogUserVal_reg[29]
```